# Linking c++ dynamic library keeps failing

Tags: c++, dll

I know there have been a lot of posts about it, however I have tried and I am still getting an error for linking my library.

In my current directory, I have created a dynamic library at

```
/bin/library_test.so
```

The source code and include files are as usual in

```
./lib/ and ./src/
```

Then I am trying to compile a simple main.cpp and link the library by doing

```
 g++ main.cpp -I/lib/ -L/bin/ -llibrary_test
```

But I keep getting errors like "ExampleClass" was not declared in this scope, meaning I have not linked the library, right? As this class is contained in my library cpp/header files.

Am I missing something in the linking, or should I add some include command in my main.cpp file??

Comment: "meaning I have not linked the library, right" - no, it doesn't mean that. That is not a linker error message. It probably means you have not included the necessary header files.

Comment: So, I should include the header files of the library or? Or how to solve this

Comment: As firtst, change `-I/lib/` with `-Isrc -Ilib`. Then you should also check out the naming convention for shared library in unix (`libLIBRARYNAME.so`, you link with `-lLIBRARYNAME`). And also, there is a difference between `/lib` and `lib` as paths: the first starts from the root of the filesystem, the latter is relative to the current directory

Comment: You need to `#include` the required header files in your C++ source code.

Comment: Thank you Matteo for the hint about the naming convention, I was not aware of that!

Comment: However, I have changed all of your advices (so renamed the library, added full paths to the command, but now I am getting:
`./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. So again to verify my linking is correct 
`g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -Isrc -Ilib -Lbin -lTest`

Comment: You are welcome, but your problem is before linking, in compilation phase. For some reason you are not including the headers that define `ExampleClass`, and it can be because of a missing include or because you are not telling to the compiler the right directory where to search for them (the  `-I` option)

Comment: Ok that is another problem: the path `/bin/` path is not a common directory for searching for a library. You should put your library in `/usr/lib` or better in `/usr/local/lib`, then run again the binary

Comment: Hey Matteo, thank you for the advice. I have tried to put it into `/usr/local/lib` and for that case it did not work, however for the first one `/usr/lib` it works fine. Just a question to clarify my understanding, shoudln't the -L command tell the linker where to search for the library, so why do I have to put it in that directory so that it works?

Comment: I'm writing an answer to explain that

Comment: Ok thanks. I also have another question. So after I have linked the library properly, shouldn't it then be enough to write  `#include <LIBRARYNAME/header.hpp>` then giving the paths by the command  `-I`. However when I do this, the program cannot find the headers..

Comment: As several people have pointed out to you, this is not an issue about linking. You cannot link the library without compiling your own code correctly first.

Comment: This might just be a misunderstanding of relative and absolute directories `-L/bin/` is different from `-Lbin/`. The former won't find things in `./bin/`

Answer (score 1):

There are several stuff to check in your command and setup. Also please check out the [C++ compilation phases](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/%7Emcmahon/CS241/Notes/compile.html). You need to understand that to fully understand your issues.

Looking at the comment you made you had 3 main problem in:

1. Compilation (after preprocessing and before assembling and linking)
2. Linking (still while compiler is running)
3. Runtime linking (during execution of the compiled binary)

#### Compilation

The error you are receiving is in compilation phase, before linking the binary. This error can be generated either because:

- you forgot the `#include` for the header that defines `ExampleClass`
- you are not telling the compiler the correct path for searching for headers. In your command you are telling the compiler to search the headers in `/lib` (a directory that start from the root of the filesystem) while I'm quite sure you want to search for them in a directory relative to your current working directory, meaning `-Ilib -Isrc`.

  By the way, I strongly suggest you to put all your source file in a `src` directory and all the headers in an `include` directory, that this what is usually done in complex C/C++ projects.

#### Linking

Once you correct the compilation phase, you will probably get a linking issue, because your library is not following the naming convention used in linux for shared objects. The filename for the library `LIBRARYNAME` should be `libLIBRARYNAME.so`.

In some cases you may have more than one version of a library, thus it is possible to add the version with a [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) convention after the `so` extension (for example `libLIBRARYVERSION.so.2.1` for the version 2.1 of your library).

To link the aforementioned library you must use the `-lLIBRARYNAME` option.

In order to inform your compiler where to find the library at linking time, you should provide the path with the `-L`, but this option informs only the compiler and does not save the position of such library in the executable.

#### Runtime Linking

In this case there are two main scenarios (I will be a little sloppy, but just to point you in the right direction. A complete explanation may require a lot more space... and time):

- You can hardcode the position of the shared library in your binary by using the [`rpath`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath), but if you distribute your application the end user must have the lib in the same path you specified via rpath, and this is why I tend to avoid this solution.
- Modern linux system are capable of search for the a required shared object (this is the reason why there is a naming convention). The search is performed in *trusted directories*, and the searching path are configured via [`ldconfig`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) configuration file (or the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable). When a new library is installed in a searching path, the cache of the runtime linker should be refreshed (again, this is done via `ldconfig` or via reboot). I strongly suggest you to read the link about `ldconfig` since it explains you how to configure a new searching path (like `/usr/local/lib` in your case).

You can check if a binary is able to find all the required shared object through the command `ldd BINARY_NAME` (in your case `ldd a.out`).